# How to find a List<Transform> in c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

So Im having a Issue where I have player prefab. And i am trying to access my gameobject which is outside the prefab and i have no way of adding it to my player without adding it to my prefab so my question is how do i find the list of transforms in my script. I tried to use tags but i kept getting a error msg?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DualHooks : MonoBehaviour
{
[Header("References")]
public List<LineRenderer> lineRenderers;
public List<Transform> gunTips;
public Transform cam;
public Transform player;
public LayerMask whatIsGrappleable;
public PlayerController pc;

[Header("Swinging")]
private float maxSwingDistance = 25f;
private List<Vector3> swingPoints;
private List<SpringJoint> joints;

[Header("Grappling")]
public float maxGrappleDistance;
public float grappleDelayTime;
public float overshootYAxis;

private List<bool> grapplesActive;

[Header("Cooldown")]
public float grapplingCd;
private float grapplingCdTimer;

[Header("OdmGear")]
public Transform orientation;
public Rigidbody rb;
public float horizontalThrustForce;
public float forwardThrustForce;
public float extendCableSpeed;

[Header("Prediction")]
public List<RaycastHit> predictionHits;
public List<Transform> predictionPoints;
public float predictionSphereCastRadius;

[Header("Input")]
public KeyCode swingKey1 = KeyCode.E;
public KeyCode swingKey2 = KeyCode.S;


[Header("DualSwinging")]
public int amountOfSwingPoints = 2;
public List<Transform> pointAimers;
private List<bool> swingsActive;

private void Start()
{
    ListSetup();

    
}

private void ListSetup()
{
    predictionHits = new List<RaycastHit>();

    swingPoints = new List<Vector3>();
    joints = new List<SpringJoint>();

    swingsActive = new List<bool>();
    grapplesActive = new List<bool>();

    currentGrapplePositions = new List<Vector3>();

    for (int i = 0; i < amountOfSwingPoints; i++)
    {
        predictionHits.Add(new RaycastHit());
        joints.Add(null);
        swingPoints.Add(Vector3.zero);
        swingsActive.Add(false);
        grapplesActive.Add(false);
        currentGrapplePositions.Add(Vector3.zero);
    }
}

private void Update()
{
    MyInput();
    CheckForSwingPoints();

    if (joints[0] != null || joints[1] != null) OdmGearMovement();

    if (grapplingCdTimer > 0)
        grapplingCdTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
}

private void LateUpdate()
{
    DrawRope();
}

private void MyInput()
{
    // starting swings or grapples depends on whether or not shift is pressed
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(swingKey1)) StartGrapple(0);
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(swingKey2)) StartGrapple(1);
    }
    else
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(swingKey1)) StartSwing(0);
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(swingKey2)) StartSwing(1);
    }

    // stopping is always possible
    //if (Input.GetKeyUp(swingKey1)) StopGrapple(0);
    //if (Input.GetKeyUp(swingKey2)) StopGrapple(1);
    if (Input.GetKeyUp(swingKey1)) StopSwing(0);
    if (Input.GetKeyUp(swingKey2)) StopSwing(1);
}

private void CheckForSwingPoints()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < amountOfSwingPoints; i++)
    {
        if (swingsActive[i]) { /* Do Nothing */ }
        else
        {
            RaycastHit sphereCastHit;
            Physics.SphereCast(pointAimers[i].position, predictionSphereCastRadius, pointAimers[i].forward,
                                out sphereCastHit, maxSwingDistance, whatIsGrappleable);

            RaycastHit raycastHit;
            Physics.Raycast(cam.position, cam.forward,
                                out raycastHit, maxSwingDistance, whatIsGrappleable);

            Vector3 realHitPoint;

            // Option 1 - Direct Hit
            if (raycastHit.point != Vector3.zero)
                realHitPoint = raycastHit.point;

            // Option 2 - Indirect (predicted) Hit
            else if (sphereCastHit.point != Vector3.zero)
                realHitPoint = sphereCastHit.point;

            // Option 3 - Miss
            else
                realHitPoint = Vector3.zero;

            // realHitPoint found
            if (realHitPoint != Vector3.zero)
            {
                predictionPoints[i].gameObject.SetActive(true);
                predictionPoints[i].position = realHitPoint;
            }
            // realHitPoint not found
            else
            {
                predictionPoints[i].gameObject.SetActive(false);
            }

            predictionHits[i] = raycastHit.point == Vector3.zero ? sphereCastHit : raycastHit;
        }
    }
}

#region Swinging

private void StartSwing(int swingIndex)
{
    // return if predictionHit not found
    if (predictionHits[swingIndex].point == Vector3.zero) return;

    // deactivate active grapple
    CancelActiveGrapples();
    pc.ResetRestrictions();

    pc.swinging = true;
    swingsActive[swingIndex] = true;

    swingPoints[swingIndex] = predictionHits[swingIndex].point;
    joints[swingIndex] = player.gameObject.AddComponent<SpringJoint>();
    joints[swingIndex].autoConfigureConnectedAnchor = false;
    joints[swingIndex].connectedAnchor = swingPoints[swingIndex];

    float distanceFromPoint = Vector3.Distance(player.position, swingPoints[swingIndex]);

    // the distance grapple will try to keep from grapple point. 
    joints[swingIndex].maxDistance = distanceFromPoint * 0.8f;
    joints[swingIndex].minDistance = distanceFromPoint * 0.25f;

    // customize values as you like
    joints[swingIndex].spring = 15f;
    joints[swingIndex].damper = 7f;
    joints[swingIndex].massScale = 4.5f;

    lineRenderers[swingIndex].positionCount = 2;
    currentGrapplePositions[swingIndex] = gunTips[swingIndex].position;
}

public void StopSwing(int swingIndex)
{
    pc.swinging = false;

    swingsActive[swingIndex] = false;

    Destroy(joints[swingIndex]);
}

#endregion

#region Grappling

private void StartGrapple(int grappleIndex)
{
    if (grapplingCdTimer > 0) return;

    CancelActiveSwings();
    CancelAllGrapplesExcept(grappleIndex);

    // Case 1 - target point found
    if (predictionHits[grappleIndex].point != Vector3.zero)
    {
        Invoke(nameof(DelayedFreeze), 0.05f);

        grapplesActive[grappleIndex] = true;

        swingPoints[grappleIndex] = predictionHits[grappleIndex].point;

        StartCoroutine(ExecuteGrapple(grappleIndex));
    }

    // Case 2 - target point not found
    else
    {
        swingPoints[grappleIndex] = cam.position + cam.forward * maxGrappleDistance;

        StartCoroutine(StopGrapple(grappleIndex, grappleDelayTime));
    }

    lineRenderers[grappleIndex].positionCount = 2;
    currentGrapplePositions[grappleIndex] = gunTips[grappleIndex].position;
}

private void DelayedFreeze()
{
    pc.freeze = true;
}

private IEnumerator ExecuteGrapple(int grappleIndex)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(grappleDelayTime);

    pc.freeze = false;

    Vector3 lowestPoint = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - 1f, transform.position.z);

    float grapplePointRelativeYPos = swingPoints[grappleIndex].y - lowestPoint.y;
    float highestPointOnArc = grapplePointRelativeYPos + overshootYAxis;

    if (grapplePointRelativeYPos < 0) highestPointOnArc = overshootYAxis;

    pc.JumpToPosition(swingPoints[grappleIndex], highestPointOnArc);
}

public IEnumerator StopGrapple(int grappleIndex, float delay = 0f)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);

    pc.freeze = false;

    pc.ResetRestrictions();

    grapplesActive[grappleIndex] = false;

    grapplingCdTimer = grapplingCd;
}

#endregion

#region OdmGear

private Vector3 pullPoint;
private void OdmGearMovement()
{
    if (swingsActive[0] && !swingsActive[1]) pullPoint = swingPoints[0];
    if (swingsActive[1] && !swingsActive[0]) pullPoint = swingPoints[1];
    // get midpoint if both swing points are active
    if (swingsActive[0] && swingsActive[1])
    {
        Vector3 dirToGrapplePoint1 = swingPoints[1] - swingPoints[0];
        pullPoint = swingPoints[0] + dirToGrapplePoint1 * 0.5f;
    }

    // right
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)) rb.AddForce(orientation.right * horizontalThrustForce * Time.deltaTime);
    // left
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)) rb.AddForce(-orientation.right * horizontalThrustForce * Time.deltaTime);
    // forward
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) rb.AddForce(orientation.forward * forwardThrustForce * Time.deltaTime);
    // backward
    /// if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)) rb.AddForce(-orientation.forward * forwardThrustForce * Time.deltaTime);
    // shorten cable
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        Vector3 directionToPoint = pullPoint - transform.position;
        rb.AddForce(directionToPoint.normalized * forwardThrustForce * Time.deltaTime);

        // calculate the distance to the grapplePoint
        float distanceFromPoint = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, pullPoint);

        // the distance grapple will try to keep from grapple point.
        UpdateJoints(distanceFromPoint);

        print("shorten " + Time.time);
    }
    // extend cable
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
    {
        // calculate the distance to the grapplePoint
        float extendedDistanceFromPoint = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, pullPoint) + extendCableSpeed;

        // the distance grapple will try to keep from grapple point.
        UpdateJoints(extendedDistanceFromPoint);

        print("extend " + Time.time);
    }
}

private void UpdateJoints(float distanceFromPoint)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < joints.Count; i++)
    {
        if (joints[i] != null)
        {
            joints[i].maxDistance = distanceFromPoint * 0.8f;
            joints[i].minDistance = distanceFromPoint * 0.25f;
        }
    }
}

#endregion

#region CancleAbilities

public void CancelActiveGrapples()
{
    StartCoroutine(StopGrapple(0));
    StartCoroutine(StopGrapple(1));
}

private void CancelAllGrapplesExcept(int grappleIndex)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < amountOfSwingPoints; i++)
        if (i != grappleIndex) StartCoroutine(StopGrapple(i));
}

private void CancelActiveSwings()
{
    StopSwing(0);
    StopSwing(1);
}

#endregion

#region Visualisation

private List<Vector3> currentGrapplePositions;

private void DrawRope()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < amountOfSwingPoints; i++)
    {
        // if not grappling, don't draw rope
        if (!grapplesActive[i] && !swingsActive[i])
        {
            lineRenderers[i].positionCount = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            currentGrapplePositions[i] = Vector3.Lerp(currentGrapplePositions[i], swingPoints[i], Time.deltaTime * 8f);

            lineRenderers[i].SetPosition(0, gunTips[i].position);
            lineRenderers[i].SetPosition(1, currentGrapplePositions[i]);
        }
    }
}

#endregion
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you mean by finding a list ... Your code is quite long ... what/where exactly do you have issues with?

Comment: how do i assign multiple predictionpoints gameobjects to a player when player is a prefab

Comment: Btw your lists you setup in `ListSetup` look like they rather could/should be arrays .. I don't see that they ever change their size after initialized once

Comment: Multiple ways: Either use things like `FindObjectOfType` to get them .. or have a manager kind of object that already exists in the scene and has the list -> your player simply gathers the information from a single entry point ... or the one who instantiates the prefab also injects that information into the newly created instance